# Java LWJGL Multiple Scissor Test

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Is there any way to glEnable GL_SCISSOR_TEST inside an already enabled GL_SCISSOR_TEST? Like the following:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
GL11.glScissor(0, 0, 64, 64);

draw.rect();

GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
GL11.glScissor(32, 32, 48, 48);

draw.smallRect();

GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```

I have tried the above and it seems to not work as expected and even by looking at the code it looks very illogical but I can't think of a way around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL state variables don't nest. This is essentially the same as doing

```
bool scissor_test_enabled;

scissor_test_enabled = true;
...
scissor_test_enabled = true;
...
scissor_test_enabled = true;
```

Scissor testing won't help you with your problem. You should look at stencil testing: Using the stencil buffer you can draw arbitrary shapes, having color and depth writes disabled, writing to the stencil buffer (getting a stencil buffer must be requested just like a depth buffer). Then enable stencil testing and draw your regular geometry with color and depth writes enabled.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using a stencil buffer at all?

Comment: @DóubleParallax: Several ways, but they are all *way* more complicated than using the stencil buffer. (rendering to rgba+depth textures and drawing the cut-out shape with those to the destination / drawing the cutout shape to a texture and using that in the fragment shader to conditionally discard fragments / do additional scissor testing in the fragment shader, passing the scissor rectangles as a uniform array).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really recommend using obsolete functionality, but in the interest of completeness: In legacy OpenGL (compatibility profile) you can use the attribute stack to save/restore the scissor state:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
GL11.glScissor(0, 0, 64, 64);

draw.rect();

GL11.glPushAttrib(GL11.GL_SCISSOR_BIT);
GL11.glScissor(32, 32, 48, 48);

draw.smallRect();

GL11.glPopAttrib();

GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```

The second `glScissor()` call will still just replace the previous scissor rectangle. It will not form an intersection, or anything like that. It only allows you to easily restore the previous scissor rectangle after you're done using the smaller one. This should give you the expected behavior as long as the second rectangle is contained in the first one, as is the case in your example.

With current OpenGL, you should just remember the scissor rectangles in your code, and set the values explicitly anytime you need to change them.

Answer (score 0):

https://pastebin.com/nGbYhhAc

Body is just a rectangle with integers.

I didn't test it yet, but you can get the idea.

However this class doesn't mean to intersect your scissors.

You can use it like so:

```
ScissorTest s1 = new ScissorTest(0, 0, 64, 64);

draw.rect();

ScissorTest s2 = new ScissorTest(32, 32, 48, 48);

draw.smallRect();

s2.destroy();

// Here you can draw something in bounds of s1

s1.destroy();
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZUbya7Q2 Improved version. Now every next scissor cannot be out of bounds of previous one.